# How to fix Resharper forgetting contextual actions?

Tags: resharper, resharper-2017

Resharper loves to suggest things all the time but mine stopped working in Visual Studio 2015 **in one particular file while still working on all others**. I uninstalled and installed it again and it continued not working.

I uninstalled it again and installed Visual Studio 2017 to install Resharper again and integrate with this new version of Visual Studio.

[image]

The behaviour continues to be the same. Resharper continues to be useless and I need to fix this.

Does anyone have any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+8` (ReSharper_EnableDaemon) shortcut in this problematic file, as suggested by Reshaper support Maria Pleskunina, worked.

And the explanation why:

> Perhaps the reason is that you recently updated ReSharper to 2016.3 or
>   2017.1. By default, ReSharper 2016.3 turns off error detection for very large files and nuget files. But in ReSharper 2017.1 you can see
>   a special state in daemon indicator that notifies a user that the code
>   analysis is off:
>   https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-462257#comment=27-1802329.

They actually show up something on the screen to help but it wasn't very obvious to me. Hope it helps. See image below:
[image]